# Android: "duplicate attribute" XML error

Tags: android, xml

I have a Layout with a set of widgets on the left side, and others on the right side.

Now I want to put a button in the centre, below to two textviews (one being on the left and the other one being on the right).

I get an error ("duplicate attribute") with the following code:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_below="@id/text_left"
android:layout_below="@id/text_right"
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: u can not use android:layout_below="@id/text_right" two times in same widget.remove one

Comment: it is not the same widget. One is "@id/text_right" and the other is "@id/text_left"

Comment: can u put your xml code so i can correct it

Comment: @jaiserpe Added additional commentary in my answer to help point out that it is not the @id/text... causing the issues, as those are unique, it's the fact you are calling `layout_below`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are setting the `layout_below` twice.

If you want the layout in question to be below both of those, try combining both of the `text_left` and `text_right` into one layout and then use `layout_below` and assign it the name you gave to the layout that contains the combination of `text_left` and `text_right`.

Answer (score 50):

This error message also happens if you have the same xmlns attribute in different layouts.

In this case, xmlns:tools is repeated in layout and ConstraintLayout.
Removing it from one of the layouts should fix the problem.

```
    <layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

        <data>
            <variable
                name="item"
                type="com.myapp.SearchSettings" />
        </data>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" <-- remove this line

(it is already in layout tag)
```

Answer (score 39):

For those, accepted answer didn't work and by any change you are using the android **Data Binding** then this kind of error may come if some of the attributes are present twice in parent tag as well as child **tag**. In below example the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` are used **twice** in **parent** as well as in **child**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="pdpDescriptionViewModel"
            type="com.tottus.ui.productdescription.model.PdpDescriptionViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>


</layout>
```

to solve this ***remove duplicate attribute from the parent or child*** and it should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="pdpDescriptionViewModel"
            type="com.tottus.ui.productdescription.model.PdpDescriptionViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>


</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had exactly this problem with a `android:background="@color/black"` in <layout> and <ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `layout_below` twice.

```
android:layout_below="@id/text_left"
android:layout_below="@id/text_right"
```

You can only set this once per widget which in this case is your `Button`. You are essentially  trying to tell the `Button` to place itself below two *different* items by way of calling `android:layout_below` multiple times.

If the end result is not what you expect using only one of the `TextViews` you may have to adjust your reference point to something which spans the entire width, or perhaps wrap your `TextViews` in a `LinearLayout` and use that as your reference point. It may be easier to also switch layout types at the root level, moving to a `LinearLayout` and nesting them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose one of your `android:layout_below`. You cannot have both.